# Remove first <p> tag using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am trying to convert QTI standard xml for Multiple choice question type to XHTML file using XSLT. I am finding difficulties in removing first 'p' tag from the 'simpleChoice' tag value.

Following is the QTI which i am trying to covert to XHTML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assessmentItem xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1 http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1.xsd" identifier="choice" title="Item Title will come here" adaptive="false" timeDependent="false" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <responseDeclaration identifier="RESPONSE" cardinality="single" baseType="identifier">
    <correctResponse>
      <value>ChoiceA</value>
    </correctResponse>
  </responseDeclaration>
  <outcomeDeclaration identifier="SCORE" cardinality="single" baseType="integer">
    <defaultValue>
      <value>0</value>
    </defaultValue>
  </outcomeDeclaration>
  <itemBody>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="instruction">Select the correct options</div>
      <choiceInteraction responseIdentifier="RESPONSE" shuffle="false" maxChoices="1">
        <prompt>
            <div id="stem">
                <p>Question will appear here</p>
            </div>
        </prompt>
        <simpleChoice identifier="ChoiceA"><p> answer's first P tag</p> <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="ChoiceB"><p> answer's first P tag</p> <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="ChoiceC"><p> answer's first P tag</p> <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="ChoiceD"><p> answer's first P tag</p> <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="ChoiceE"><p> answer's first P tag</p> <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</simpleChoice>
      </choiceInteraction>
    </div>
  </itemBody>
  <responseProcessing template="http://www.imsglobal.org/question/qti_v2p1/rptemplates/match_correct" />
</assessmentItem>
```

I am looking at the following output for the options

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="option1">
      <label>A.</label>
      <div class="optionContent">answer's first P tag<p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
    </div>          
    <div id="option2">
      <label>B.</label>
      <div class="optionContent">answer's first P tag<p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
    </div>
    <div id="option3">
      <label>C.</label>
      <div class="optionContent">answer's first P tag<p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
    </div>
    <div id="option4">
      <label>D.</label>
      <div class="optionContent">answer's first P tag<p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
    </div>
    <div id="option5">
      <label>E.</label>
      <div class="optionContent">answer's first P tag<p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The desire output i need is to remove first 'p' tag from the 'simpleChoice' tag.

I had tried doing that using following styles

```
<xsl:for-each select="//simpleChoice[$vCurrentIndex]/*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'p' and position() = 1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="children" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="children" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

After doing this i am getting following output. The output is not considering any values which are not within the P tag. Getting output for three P tags only.

```
<div class="optionContent">answer's second P tag<p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p></div>
```

Your help will really help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to XSLT is wrong. Remove all the `<xsl:for-each>` in your entire stylesheet. You don't need them and should not use them. They indicate that you think procedurally and XSLT is not a procedural language.

This task is very simple if you use template matching instead of `for-each`. Also use proper namespace declarations in your XSL instead of using `local-name()` everywhere.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:qti="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1"
  exclude-result-prefixes="qti"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//qti:simpleChoice" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity template: this is the base of the entire process -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- helper: elements in the qti namespace output their local name -->
  <xsl:template match="qti:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="qti:simpleChoice">
    <div id="option{position()}">
      <label>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@identifier, 7), '.')" />
      </label>
      <div class="optionContent">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </div>  
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- the first p in a simpleChoice will just output its contents -->
  <xsl:template match="qti:simpleChoice/qti:p[1]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (see http://www.xmlplayground.com/IiKDkY)

```
<root>
  <div id="option1">
    <label>A.</label>
    <div class="optionContent"> answer's first P tag <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
  </div>
  <div id="option2">
    <label>B.</label>
    <div class="optionContent"> answer's first P tag <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
  </div>
  <div id="option3">
    <label>C.</label>
    <div class="optionContent"> answer's first P tag <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
  </div>
  <div id="option4">
    <label>D.</label>
    <div class="optionContent"> answer's first P tag <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
  </div>
  <div id="option5">
    <label>E.</label>
    <div class="optionContent"> answer's first P tag <p> answer's second P tag</p> <p> answer's third P tag</p> <p> answer's forth P tag</p> and text without p tag</div>
  </div>
</root>
```

Comment: Good answer, but there are more than one errors in the presented transformation. Did you try to run it?

Comment: @Dimitre: I changed it after a (now-deleted) comment by somebody. My first version had an empty template (`<xsl:template match="qti:simpleChoice/qti:p[1]" />`) - That's one fixed copy/paste mistake. The template runs on xmlplayground (link above). I can't see the other error?

Comment: Tomalak, The "xsi" namespace is undefined.

Comment: Shouldn't you better remove the identity transform? We're transforming from the namespace `http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1` to XHTML. An identity transform would result in the wrong namespace.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, That helped me to solve my problem. I really appreciate your prompt reply.

Comment: @ThomasW, The identity rule isn't affected by nodes belonging to namespaces, so it is perfectly OK to use in that case.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev You're right, the `xsi` namespace is superfluous in the `exclude-result-prefixes`. Not exactly an error, but still unnecessary. I'll remove it.

Comment: @Dimitre You are right. I tested it on xmlplayground (which uses PHP and thus libxml2 internally), where it worked. Thanks for the tip, will pay attention to this in the future.

Comment: @Tomalak, I never use any "playground" or "cake" -- due to such reasons.

Answer (score 2):

> The desire output i need is to remove first 'p' tag from the
>   'simpleChoice' tag.

I hope I understood your problem right - you want to show first P like a DIV or like a SPAN without any marging and etc., right?

Then I think the better way is to use content of `<simpleChoice>...</simpleChoice>` as is. But in your CSS file for `<div class="optionContent">` to apply an additional style for first P tag. Something like this:

```
.optionContent > p
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: +1 I suppose your answer is more to the point than mine. The OP just seems to have a presentation issue, not a structure issue. Presentation issues should be solved with CSS.